# jQuery/CSS3 easing elements into empty space left after a fade

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm working on a site where there will be a centered list of elements, laid out horizontally.  The user is able to filter the elements based on some anchors below the actual element display.  I've set up a jsfiddle demonstrating the basic functionality here: http://jsfiddle.net/T6N9G/1/

In the example above, the items that are meant to disappear slowly fade out, which is fine.  The problem is that the other elements "jump" to fill the space that is left when the hidden elements finally get `display: none`. I'm looking for a way to ease the visible elements into the new space.

In the fiddle above, the following lines need adjustment (or, if possible, a CSS3 transition can be applied to the elements):

```
$("a").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var color = $(this).attr("class");
    var $show = $(".container .item." + color);
    var $hide = $(".container .item:not(." + color + ")");

    $show.fadeIn();  // Change Me?
    $hide.fadeOut(); // Change Me?
});
```

I have full control over the project, but am hoping to avoid including misc. JS libraries to accomplish minor tasks like this.  Is there a jQuery UI effect, or a CSS3 transition that will do what I need?

Answer (score 4):

You can use animation chaining to animate the opacity separately.

http://jsfiddle.net/CT5Ys/1/

```
$show.show(200).animate({opacity: 1}, {duration: 200});
$hide.animate({opacity: 0}, {duration: 200}).hide(200);
```

Comment: This works, but still has quirks.  If I toggle from green/blue and back, you'll notice the elements "slide" into the middle in a slightly strange way.  This is a great start though, and will probably just need a minor tweak to perfect.

Comment: sounds like you want different behaviour depending on what items are already visible http://jsfiddle.net/CT5Ys/7/

Answer (score 0):

One solution using CSS transitions.

I set the hidden class with jQuery

```
$("a").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var color = $(this).attr("class");
    var $show = $(".container .item." + color);
    var $hide = $(".container .item:not(." + color + ")");

    $show.removeClass("hidden");
    $hide.addClass("hidden");

});
```

This class changes opacity and size:

```
.hidden {
    width: 0px !important;
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
    margin-right: -5px !important;
}
```

And this changes have a transition set

```
.container .item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: opacity 1s 0s, width 1s 0.5s, margin 1s 0.5s;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6N9G/5/)

You can play with the times to achive different styles